# Need Help Python 3 ISBN check digit

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I want my code to be able to repeat after the 11 digit has been out-puted.
So far my code prints out at the end 'Would you like to try again? Enter 'y' for Yes and 'n' for No:' Then If I type n it exits the program which I want :D but I want it so If i type y it goes back and asks the user to input a 10 digit Number. I need to define y I have attempted many ways for it to return but it doesn't work can someone please help me.

```
ISBN=input("Please enter a 10 digit number for the ISBN check digit:  ")

while len(ISBN)!= 10:

    print("Please try again and make sure you entered 10 digits.")
    ISBN=int(input("Please enter the 10 digit number again: "))
    continue

else:
    D1 =int(ISBN[0])*11
    D2 =int(ISBN[1])*10
    D3 =int(ISBN[2])*9
    D4 =int(ISBN[3])*8
    D5 =int(ISBN[4])*7
    D6 =int(ISBN[5])*6
    D7 =int(ISBN[6])*5
    D8 =int(ISBN[7])*4
    D9 =int(ISBN[8])*3
    D10=int(ISBN[9])*2
    Sum=(D1+D2+D3+D4+D5+D6+D7+D8+D9+D10)
    Mod=Sum%11
    D11=11-Mod
    if D11==10:
        D11='X'
    ISBNNumber=str(ISBN)+str(D11)
    print("Your 11 digit ISBN Number is *" + ISBNNumber + "*")

while True:
    close = input("Would you like to try again? Enter 'y' for Yes and 'n' for No: ")
    if close.lower() in ("n", "no"):
        print("Exiting")
        break
```

Comment: Since python indentation is important, please make sure the code you pasted is indented correctly. The source as it is right now will fail on syntax error.

Comment: Your `while True` loop is *after* the code has done its work. You need to wrap the whole thing in `while True`!

Comment: what @jonrsharpe says... Note: Try to avoid built in names as variablenames (sum)

Comment: One of your problems is conversion from integer to string. In your implementation the user has put the number like "1293432344".

Answer (score -2):

Wrong identation.

Try this:

```
while True:
    close = input("Would you like to try again? Enter 'y' for Yes and 'n' for No: ")
    if close.lower() in ("n", "no"):
        print("Exiting")
        break
```